# Launching 4 programs in the background from bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a small problem, I have created 4 small programs that are supposed to simulate the operation of 2 sensors. I need them to run one after the other, so I put them in a bash script to make it easier.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/sensors/RANSensor
nohup python3 ~/sensors/RANSensor/DataGenerator.py -i ~/sensors/RANSensor/pm.csv > ~/output1.log 2>&1 &
cd ~/sensors/RANSensor
nohup python3 ~/sensors/RANSensor/main.py -i ~/sensors/RANSensor/pm.csv -o ~/data > ~/output2.log 2>&1 &
cd ~/sensors/RanTestSensor/target
nohup java -jar ~/sensors/RanTestSensor/target/RanTestSensor-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -p ~/sensors/RanTestSensor/src/main/resources/metric.generator.properties >~/output3.txt 2>&1 &
cd ~/sensors/UserSesnsor/target
nohup java -jar ~/sensors/UserSesnsor/target/UsersSensor-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -p ~/sensors/UserSesnsor/src/main/resources/metric.generator.properties >~/output7.txt 2>&1 &
```

However, here comes the problem because when I run the script the commands don't run. I know this because the output files are empty and the generated data files (generated by python scripts) are not updated. The `jobs -l` command doesn't show anything either. I know the commands are correct because if I run them manually in the terminal everything works. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

**The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.02 without Desktop.**

**I gave all scripts rights 777.**

Thanks in advance for any help.

### The answer to my problem is in the comments.

Comment: "I need them to run one after the other" – You're trying to start them in some sequence, but they may keep running in parallel. Is this OK? Additionally only the forked shells start in the sequence. I guess there is no guarantee they exec to `nohup`s in this exact sequence or if `nohup`s exec to `python3` or `java` in this sequence, or if these tools start interpreting the respective files in this sequence. What if you add `sleep 3` after each `cd`? It's not a perfect approach, but at least it may show you if the problem is in timing.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski What I meant was that the programs should start one after the other and run simultaneously. First, two python3 programs that simulate data for sensors are started, and then java programs, i.e. sensors.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The `sleep 3` command didn't work. However, I expected this because if the problem was the start time of the commands, the logs (output files) would show some error, but they are empty.

Comment: How exactly do you run the script?

Comment: bash ~/sensors/sensorStart.sh

Comment: It seems like the `cd` commands are completely unnecessary, as you don't use relative paths (other than to your HOME) anywhere. Why do you need `nohup` for every command? Use it when running your "sensorStart" script instead. `chmod 777` is never the right answer.

Comment: Also, if you want them to run one after the other - why do you append `&` to your commands? That does exactly the opposite! It runs those commands in the **background**

Comment: Putting nohup at script start helped. I don't know how, but most importantly, it works. Thank you both very much for your help.

Comment: @Panki What I meant was that the programs must start one after the other, not that the next one should execute after the first one finishes.